# Accessing Sharepoint Subfolders using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, sharepoint

sorry, if this question has been asked before, but I did not find anything really relatable.

On a Sharepoint which requires authentication, an excel file is stored which is supposed to import files stored in a subfolder of the Sharepoint. While I have no experience with this, using Trial and Error I got to the point, that I map the sharepoint to a new Network drive and try to access it that way. The storing works, but when I access the new drive to create a File System Object I get an Error message telling me that the path is not found. I guess this is a problem with missing authentication. When I navigate to the drive and the folder I want to access in the explorer beforehand, everything problematic works fine. So I'm guessing the authentication somehow... gets missing in the process? I feel like I'm lacking some basic understanding of the whole authentication process of NetworkObjects and I hope, someone could point me in the right direction

```
    Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error GoTo Label1:
    NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive "X:" ', bForce:=True
Label1:
    On Error GoTo Label2:
    NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "X:", SharepointAdress, False, UserName,
    Password
Label2:
    Set Directory = FSO.GetFolder(SharepointAdress & 
    "Subfolder\subsubfolder\")
```

This is the problematic code, the error handers are simply to catch, if the drive has already been created before / doesn't exist yet. The drive gets removed and added again, I thought it would make sense to "authenticate" the drive in every iteration, but obviously that was not the problem.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: what is the value of `SharepointAdress`?  (And I assume you realize it's misspelled?)

Comment: Its "\\teamshare.organisation.org\team\12345\Projectarea\", with information about the company removed

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` the top of the module?  If not, add that as the first line and **compile** the code ( **[Alt]**+**[D]**  **[Alt]**+**[L]**  ) to make sure your variables are declared and that spelling matches, etc.  (If you get & fix an issue, re-compile, to check again, etc, until all issues are taken care of.)

Comment: Option Explicit is on top of module. Compiling the code gets me as far as as the FSO creation. Thank you for helping already!